# How to get Image with exif data while using DKImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, image, exif

I am  using `DKImagePickerController` and i want to upload image to  server with `exif` data. But this picker removes `exif` data from image.

Comment: can you post the code snippet what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let originalAsset = asset.originalAsset {
  let location = originalAsset.location
  debugPrint("lat:\(location?.coordinate.latitude),lng:\(location?.coordinate.longitude)")
  let createTime = originalAsset.creationDate
}
```